# Cannot find AWS_KEY_ID to connect to Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am just getting started using Boto3 to connect to AWS, and I cannot get it to work.

This is my code:

```
#client

client = boto3.client('s3')

list_bucket=client.list_buckets()

print(list_bucket)
```

This is the error message I receive:

> botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

I tried to set up CLI access through following tutorials, and I created a file called credentials within my .aws/ folder that looks like this (with my actual keys instead of blanks):

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ________________
aws_secret_access_key = ____________________________
```

From my understanding, boto3 should automatically find the aws_access_key_id from my credentials file in my .aws/ folder, but that doesn't appear to be working.

Does anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: Download aws cli if you dont' have it https://github.com/aws/aws-cli then use `aws configure` in the terminal to set up your credentials. It will put your credentials where they need to be

Comment: Sure! I just wrote a solution you can mark as the answer if you think it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to download AWS cli and use the `aws configure` command to put the config file in the correct location